# hacer que un listview ocupe toda la pantalla

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una app donde en una de las activities tengo un listview. Es un listview dinamico que se completa con un arrayadapter propio, por lo que su extension es desconocida. Me gustaria que cuando excede del tamaño de la pantalla llegue hasta abajo y con scroll baje.

PAra conseguir esto, tengo que darle un tamaño fijo a la lista,concretamente de 471, para que ocupe gran parte de la pantalla y pued subir y bajar. Si le doy la propuedad match_parent se queda en una sola fila, y se queda arriba un solo elemento, puedo hacer scroll pero se quedan todos los elementos ahi,arriba y pequeños.

Hay alguna manera de ajustar para todas las pantallas la lista y que quede completa en la pantalla?

os dejo el layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.oftecnica2.agendajose.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/lista"
                android:divider="@drawable/separador"
                android:layout_height="475dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Aqui el layout propio que uso para rellenar el listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="53dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/iconoreunion" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Nº"
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/txtnumero"
                        android:paddingRight="30dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/Act1Fecha"
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/txtfecha"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/Act1Nombre"
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/txtnombre"
                        android:paddingRight="30dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: has probado con android:layout_height="Wrap_content" ?

Comment: si hago eso se ajusta a una sola fila, y me muestra todo en un espacio pequeño

Comment: añado el layout de del elemento que va dentro.

Comment: @SergioCv ¿Si utilizas match_parent en vez de 475dp dentro del ListView es cuando te aparece una sola fila?

Comment: eso es @Error404

Comment: @SergioCv Esta tarde-noche te lo miro si nadie te ha contestado aún que ahora no puedo.

Comment: muchas gracias @Error404 , me esta dando mucho dolor de cabeza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es que tener un `listview` dentro de un `scrollview` es muy mala idea, si necesitas tener un listview con vistas superiores o inferiores debes añadirle las vistas por encima o por debajo con los métodos `addHeaderView()` y `addFooterView()`.

Lo que seguramente te esté pasando es que el scrollView está cogiendo el tamaño del listview para que el scrollview tenga el tamaño de toda la pantalla añádele:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Un saludo

Comment: esto lo ha solucionado! pero me intriga...por que es una mala practica meter una lista en un scroll? ya por aprendizaje,al margen de lo preguntado inicialmente. Por supuesto gracias por todo :)

Comment: @SergioCv Muy cierto lo que comenta Fabio "listview dentro de un scrollview es muy mala idea (practica) ".

Comment: es mala idea porque recuerda que el listview tiene su propio scroll asi que realmente no hace falta ponerlo dentro de un scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer esto..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Para que no te compliques.. de esta forma sencilla tendrías tu pantalla sólo para mostrar el ListView, bueno si el requerimiento lo pide.

Comment: Esto es lo que ya tiene en su layout contenedor =) , por cierto de donde eres marlopya?

Comment: Soy de perúlandia :)

Answer (score 1):

Haz intentado con quitar el Action Bar

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: es cierto escapó de cualquier respuesta, buena respuesta joven!
pero ahora agregarlo en los estilos influiría en todos los que tenga dicho estilo.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente en tu contenedor principal `LinearLayout`,  Tienes definido:

```
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Lo cual es correcto, pero tienes definido un padding el cual va a generar espacio:

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Elimina los padding.

Otro punto importante es que no necesitas un `Scrollview` para contener el ListView ya que este tiene su propio Scroll, elimina el `ScrollView` y su `LinearLayout`.

Este es un ejemplo:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

         <ListView
              android:id="@+id/list"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="match_parent">
         </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: y al eliminarlos...añado alguna otra propiedad?

Comment: porque sigue quedandose en una linea

Comment: Elimina el ScrollView y su LinearLayout Sergio.

Comment: Aunque con el comentario de antes del compañero ya lo he solucionado, he eliminado el scrollview, no sabia que era una mala practica, gracias por todo Elena...aunque me gustaria saber por que me han puesto un -1...

Comment: Desconozco porque te pusieron esa calificación no veo que tu pregunta sea incorrecta, no te preocupes Sergio. Por cierto tener un Scroll dentro de otro (en este caso el del ListView) como comentas es una mala practica, Sonrie! saludos!. =)

Comment: Gracias por todo! siempre es un placer aprender de vosotros!